# How should I plaster a hole in the wall on top of thermalite?

Tags: drywall, plaster

I have a hole in my wall which is about 300x300mm, approx. 30mm deep going back to thermalite block. I only have experience with smaller patching-up jobs, so I'm unsure how to approach it.

My instinct is to use a piece of plasterboard, somehow attaching it to the thermalite, filling in the gap with plaster mix, then using plaster tape and smoothing with another layer of plaster mix. Is this the right approach?

If this is right, what should I use to adhere the plaster board to the thermalite?

Comment: I'm confused. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermalite

Comment: Oh. Maybe you should just call them "concrete" or "masonry" blocks unless it's important to mention the brand name for some reason. http://forterra.co.uk/thermalite-and-aggregrate-blocks/thermalite-aircrete-blocks

Comment: @isherwood sorry, they're ubiquitous in the UK. They're pretty unique, in that they are quite soft and porous but good at insulating. I guess you don't have them in the states!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from the US, so I'm not familiar with them either, but on page 42 and 45 of the [Forterra product spec sheet](http://forterra.co.uk/plugins/downloads/files/thermalite_technical_manual_2015.pdf) it mentions plasterboard being adhered on dabs... which means using materials and methods like the ones found here:

http://www.ultimatehandyman.co.uk/how-to/plastering/direct-bond

Comment: That's some great detective work! Thanks very much, I wouldn't have thought about checking the product spec sheet.